# Prevent a shell fork from living longer than its initiator?

Tags: bash, background-process, fork, jobs, concurrency

If I have a Bash script like:

```
function repeat {
    while :; do
        echo repeating; sleep 1
    done
}
repeat &
echo running once
```

`running once` is printed once but `repeat`'s fork lives forever, printing endlessly.

How should I prevent `repeat` from continuing to run after the script which created it has exited?

I thought maybe explicitly instantiating a new `bash -c` interpreter would force it to exit as its parent has disappeared, but I guess orphaned processes are adopted by `init` or  PID 1.

Testing this using another file:

```
# repeat.bash
while :; do echo repeating; sleep 1; done

# fork.bash
bash -c "./repeat.bash & echo an exiting command"
```

Running `./fork.bash` still causes `repeat.bash` to continue to run in the background forever.

The simple and lazy solution is to add the line to `fork.bash`:

```
pkill repeat.bash
```

But you had better not have another important process with that name, or it will also be obliterated.

1. I wonder, if there is a better or accepted way to handle background jobs in forked shells that should exit when the script (or process) that created them has exited?
2. If there is no better way than blindly `pkilling` all processes with the same name, how should a repeating job that runs alongside something like a webserver be handled to exit? **I want to avoid a `cron` job because the script is in a `git` repository, and the code should be self-contained without changing system files in `/etc/`.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kills the background process before the script exits:

```
trap '[ "$pid" ] && kill "$pid"' EXIT

function repeat {
    while :; do
        echo repeating; sleep 1
    done
}
repeat &
pid=$!
echo running once
```

#### How it works

- `trap '[ "$pid" ] && kill "$pid"' EXIT`

  This creates a *trap*.  Whenever the script is about to exit, the commands in single-quotes will be run.  That command checks to see if the shell variable `pid` has been assigned a non-empty value.  If it has, then the process associated with `pid` is killed.
- `pid=$!`

  This saves the process id of the preceding background command (`repeat &`) in the shell variable `pid`.

#### Improvement

As [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick) points out in the comments, there is a chance that the script could be killed *after* the background process starts but *before* the `pid` variable is set.  We can handle that case with this code:

```
my_exit() {
    [ "$racing" ] && pid=$!
    [ "$pid" ] && kill "$pid"
}
trap my_exit EXIT

function repeat {
    while :; do
        echo repeating; sleep 1
    done
}

racing=Y
repeat &
pid=$!
racing=

echo running once
```

Comment: You can avoid the need for the `[ "$pid" ]` conditional by just putting the trap after the `repeat &`. You can also avoid the need for a variable by doing `trap "kill $!" EXIT`.

Comment: @Patrick You are exactly right but the key advantage to the approach above is that it scales well as the complexity of the script increases.  If, for example, the script expands to have more than one function that has to be killed or maybe a temporary file that needs to be deleted or the logical flow becomes more complex, then the approach of a single trap statement at the top with tests like `[ "$pid1" ]` is easy to maintain and extend.

Comment: @Patrick, setting the trap after running the background process runs the risk of the someone killing the script _just_ after the background process is started, but before the trap is set up. Better to avoid race conditions like that.

Comment: @ilkkachu Setting the variable after running the background process runs the risk of the someone killing the script *just* after the background process is started, but before the variable is set up.

Comment: @Patrick, well, that's also true, and probably unavoidable. Except by killing via job id, but I don't know if there's a good way to get the jobid except by counting how many are used.

Comment: well if job control is enabled, you have `jobs -p`

Comment: I just added code to handle the the special case that @Patrick points out.

Answer (score 3):

The `tcsh` shell has a `hup` command to tell the shell to kill the command upon exit:

```
hup mycommand...
```

That doesn't help for running function as `tcsh` has no support for functions though.

In `zsh`, when job control is enabled, that's done by default for all background jobs.

```
$ zsh -c 'set -m; sleep 2 &'; ps
[1] 23672
zsh:1: warning: 1 jobs SIGHUPed
```

Enabling job control in scripts can have side effects though.

`bash` can do it as well but only when interactive (though calling it with -i on a script will also do it) and only when a login shell (!?). And you need to enabled the `huponexit` option. So:

```
 bash -O huponexit -lic 'sleep 2 &'
```

That has quite a few side effects though so is probably not a good idea.

Another option with `zsh` would be to kill all known running children processes (in any case we can't easily know about grand-children (nor that we would always want to kill them)) upon exit. `zsh` makes that available in the `$jobstates` associative array:

```
TRAPEXIT() kill -s HUP ${${jobstates[(R)running:*]/#*:/}/%=*/}
trap exit INT HUP TERM
```

Other shells don't expose their list of children, but you could kill the processes whose ppid is `$$`, like:

```
trap 'pkill -HUP -P "$$"' EXIT INT HUP TERM
```

Comment: Nice answer covering more than bash -- can you elaborate, the other undesirable side effects of `bash -O huponexit -lic`?